# Can I detect integer overflow flaws with valgrind?

Tags: valgrind, integer-overflow

Can I detect integer overflow flaws with valgrind?  and which tool in it can do that?

Comment: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.debugging.valgrind/7475

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Valgrind has no tool which can detect integer overflow.
You might maybe catch these bugs using the gcc option:

```
-ftrapv This option generates traps for signed overflow on addition, subtraction, multiplication
operations.
```